# How to empty stack history for log out and fully reset back to login screen? - React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v6

I've tried to implement a log out button in which pressed will log the user out, navigate to the `LoginScreen` and remove the stack history.

The goal is to reset it back as if when you entered the app and the only Stack Screen is the `LoginScreen`.

I tried with and without `CommonActions` with the `.reset()`:

```
export default function SettingsScreen({ navigation, userData }) {
   function logOutUser() {
      // ...
      navigation.reset({
         index: 0,
         routes: [{name: "LoginScreen"}]
      })
   }
)}
```

```
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function SettingsScreen({ navigation, userData }) {
   function logOutUser() {
      // ...
      navigation.dispatch(
         CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: {
               name: 'LoginScreen',
            },
         })
      );
   }
)}
```

What I've read this is supposed to navigate to `LoginScreen` and reset the whole Stack to only include this? When pressing log out absolutely nothing happens. Are you supposed to use `navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")` with this?

I have also tried to comprehend the docs for [StackActions reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/) (tried the `.popToTop() without any difference in stack`) and [CommonActions reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/) but none of those seem to be what will give the desired result, or just not working for me.

As I said before I just want the App completely reset as if you just entered it so when I log in no previous data is present (as it is right now, which means that even when you log in with a new user the old data is still showing).

Keep in mind that I have no experience with the class based solutions which I have seen a couple.

I will gladly expand if I missed something